# Why use CNAME in Route 53+S3 combination

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, cname-record, a-record, amazon-route53

I have been going through [Amazon's docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) on using Route 53 in conjunction with S3 to serve static websites.

The strategy they show is to do:

```
example.com A -> alias to s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (example.com bucket)
www.example.com CNAME -> www.example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

`example.com` bucket is set to host static content, and `www.example.com` bucket is set to do a permanent redirect to `example.com`.

That's fine and it works, but because I am trying to learn and understand how DNS works in detail, I don't understand why they don't simply do:

```
example.com A -> alias to s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (example.com bucket)
www.example.com A -> alias to s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (www.example.com bucket)
```

Wouldn't it help reduce one extra DNS resolution step (`A` lookup for `www.example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`)?

Is there any benefit to using CNAME here, considering that Route 53 has the ability to alias directly to buckets?

To be clear, using CNAME works, but I am trying to academically understand why they don't suggest using an A alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in terms of understanding how DNS itself works, it's important to note that there is no such thing as this *Alias* record that they recommend for `example.com`, that is entirely a Route53 feature where they behind the scenes resolve the specified name and expose a standard `A` record in DNS (whatever record type you chose when you created it, but in their example it's an `A` record).

Why they chose to not recommend using their *Alias* feature for `www.example.com` as well is not entirely obvious.
Maybe it's simply less overhead on their end if you use a regular static record?
Maybe they consider a regular static record to be more robust?
Maybe there are other records than `A` at `www.example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` that ideally should exist but that they don't feel they can ask you to add one by one as aliases (`CNAME` makes the name an alias of the other, regardless of requested record type)?

The opposite, using `CNAME` in both cases is not an option, however. As `CNAME` records cannot coexist with other data it's never possible to have a `CNAME` at the zone apex as there is always at least `SOA` and `NS` records there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the amazon stuff, but in there doc, they speak of alias record and CNAME record. both are the same. A CNAME maps a FQDN to another FQDN. For me, this is the definition of an alias (another name for the same thing). A A record only maps to an IPv4 adress (cf [RFC1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt))

note that www.example.com and example.com are 2 distinct FQDN and there is a priori no reason they are mapped with the same IP adresse(s). (e.g. fdn.fr does not have a A record nor a CNAME whereas www.fdn.fr has a CNAME)
this complicated stuff is only required "if you want to serve content from your root domain". this way, both example.com and www.example.com must maps to the same IP adress(es). A convinient way to do this is to configure one (e.g. example.com) as desired and to put a CNAME record for the other (www.example.com IN CNAME example.com).

To see what they configure for you, try to resolve your domain name (both your root zone -- example.com -- and your so called alias --www.example.com-- ) with appropriate tools (dig or nslookup):

```
dig +trace www.example.com any
dig +trace example.com any
```

I don't know the nslookup equivalent (as I use dig)

Comment: Both are not the same. `CNAME` is a DNS record type, the *alias* they have for other record types is a Route53 specific feature.